# RegExp in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

How can I implement RegExp in TypeScript?

My example:

```
var trigger = "2"
var regex = new RegExp('^[1-9]\d{0,2}$', trigger); // where I have exception in Chrome console
```

Answer (score 118):

I think you want to `test` your RegExp in TypeScript, so you have to do like this:

```
var trigger = "2",
    regexp = new RegExp('^[1-9]\d{0,2}$'),
    test = regexp.test(trigger);
alert(test + ""); // will display true
```

You should read [MDN Reference - RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), the `RegExp` object accepts two parameters `pattern` and `flags` which is nullable(can be omitted/undefined). To test your regex you have to use the `.test()` method, not passing the string you want to test inside the declaration of your RegExp!

**Why `test + ""`?**
Because `alert()` in TS accepts a string as argument, it is better to write it this way. You can try the full code [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/).

Comment: if var trigger = "10", regexp = new RegExp('^[1-9]\d{0,2}$'), test = regexp.test(trigger);
                    alert(test + ""); alert return false, it's not correctly

Comment: Replace your current regex pattern with this: `'^([0-9]\d{0,2})+$'`

Comment: Because you are creating the RegExp object from a string you will need to escape the backslash too: `new RegExp('^[1-9]\\d{0,2}$')` or use the regex literal notation: `/^[1-9]\d{0,2}$/`

Answer (score 55):

You can do just:

```
var regex = /^[1-9]\d{0,2}$/g
regex.test('2') // outputs true
```

Comment: regex.test is not a function.

Answer (score 26):

In TypeScript, the declaration is something like this:

```js
const regex : RegExp = /.+\*.+/;
```

Using RegExp constructor:

```js
const regex = new RegExp('.+\\*.+');
```

Answer (score 10):

```js
const regex = /myRegexp/

console.log('Hello myRegexp!'.replace(regex, 'World')) // = Hello World!
```

The **Regex literal notation** is commonly used to create new instances of `RegExp`

```
     regex needs no additional escaping
      v
/    regex   /   gm
^            ^   ^
start      end   optional modifiers
```

As others sugguested, you can also use the `new RegExp('myRegex')` constructor.
But you will have to be especially careful with escaping:

```
regex: 12\d45
matches: 12345
                           Extra excape because it is part of a string
                            v
const regex = new RegExp('12\\d45')
const equalRegex = /12\d45/
```

Comment: This answer saved my life ;) I wanted to create regExp inside a loop and based on values of an Enum: `for (const placeholder in PlaceholdersEnum) {
            if ( Object.keys(PlaceholdersEnum).indexOf(placeholder) !== Object.keys(PlaceholdersEnum).length - 1) {

                regex += `(\\[\\b${placeholder}\\b])|`;
            }
            else {
                console.log('last one');
                regex += `(\\[\\b${placeholder}\\b])`;
            }
        }`

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest way you can use such this thing:

```
            let regex = new RegExp('(^\w+\.\w+\.\w+$)');
let result: boolean = regex.test(this.Model.infoLink);
```