# Get the number between two characters - Typescript

Tags: regex, typescript, google-cloud-functions

I am new to Typescript and trying to make a webhook in my Google Cloud Functions.

I have a string: `C1234567890A460450P10TS1596575969702`

I want to use regex to extract the number `1234567890` from that string.
The first character `C` is fixed and does not change, the character `A` after the number is variable and can be any other alphabet.

The regex that matches the number is `(?<=C)(\d{10})(?=\w)`.

I want to know how to execute this regex in Typescript so that I can get the number into a variable(eg: `const number = [the number extracted from the string] //value 1234567890`)

**Edit 1**:

Based on the provided suggestions (which I had tried already before posting this question), here is the code I could make out of it:

```
const string = request.body.string;

let regxp = new RegExp('(?<=C)(\d{10})(?=\w)');
const number = regxp.exec(string);

response.send(number);
```

This gives a blank response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegExp in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648679/regexp-in-typescript) Or: [Regex Match value in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36303572/8967612)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed They do not help. I've updated the OP.

Comment: `let regxp = /(?<=C)\d{10}(?=\w)/;`

Comment: Your response is blank because backslashes in your RegExp need to be escaped when you are not using `/.../` format: `let regxp = new RegExp('(?<=C)(\\d{10})(?=\\w)');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two problems, you never parsed the returned string to a number with `parseInt` and `(?<=C)` (positive lookbehind) is not always supported.

Second, your regular expression can be simplified into `^C\d{10}` and a `.splice(1)` to remove the `C`.

```
const string: string = request.body.string;


const matches = s.match(/^C\d{10}/);
let number: number;
if(matches !== null) {
    number = parseInt(matches[0].slice(1));
} else {
    res.status(400).end(); // Assuming this is express
    return;
}

res.send(number); // 1234567890
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBMF4YCIDCBGATAZgCwFYA2AdgA4BOABgEFdDKDKAFdSgFQGV19zD9iehcsUqZkAbgBQ00JFgBbAIZRgACwCm8JBAB0SlaoAUAegB6qADoATAN6sAvsYCUU2RBAAbdTo8gA5ob6apoukl6wYABcYACu8gBG6gBOiDCUUgCWAGaBysHwAIQISLEeHk6SMFUwYKkADopJEOoAkmBQuQaaANqUALo6EB4ZwOqG6E4Vkm6e3r4BYC5AA)

Comment: With a few minor changes I could get it to work with my case. Thanks.